# How to play youtube video inside UItableview IOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, youtube

in my application i want to play a N number utube videos i have array of `YouTube` url in my server so now i want to view the utube video in my `UITableView` once user click the cell it has to play the particular video inside the detail view.

I have used the `HCYoutubeParser` to play the `YouTube` video without using the `UIWebView` and without redirecting to the utube. Now I'm facing some issues here

I have used the `NSObject` to fetch the `URL` and title from server and I'm using the `setDataSource`method to view the video.

My `setDataSource` code

```
  -(void)setDataSource:(videopolitical *)inVideosObj
   {
     self.title.text = inVideosObj.title;
     NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video]];
     MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]] autorelease];
     [self presentViewController:mp animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

In this above code in last line `[self presentViewController:mp animated:YES completion:nil];` its showing waring like.

```
Instance method' - presentViewController:animated:completion:'not found(return type defaults to 'id')
```

please tell me how to resolve this issue and how to play the array of utube videos inside the `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

If there is no restriction on `UIWebView` usage then I suggest to use `UIWebView`. That is very simple Here is example.

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
                        @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head><body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"",
                        youTubeUrl,
                        @"?f=gdata_videos&rel=0\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"",
                        youTubeUrl,
                        @"?f=gdata_videos&rel=0\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\" ",
                        width,
                        @"\"height=\" ",
                        height,
                        @"\"></embed></object></div></body></html>"];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[_youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.meuglobal.com"]];
```

Comment: i want to play the video with the application i not want to redirect any place is this possiable with ur code

Comment: Yes this will do what you required.

Comment: please tell where ihave declare youtubeurl

Comment: replace this varible with your url youTubeUrl

Comment: ok but [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.meuglobal.com"]]; for wt reason u have used this line do i have give any website link here

Comment: now its show error on height and width like undeclared variable

Comment: please tell me how to make it

Comment: meugloabl.com is base url. which can be nil. replace width=340 and height with 220

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51673/discussion-between-user3427551-and-macrosoft-dev)

Answer (score 0):

`NSObject` doesn't have a method called `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

You must do this in your viewController.